# Array of Buttons

Tags: android

I am having an 20 Buttons as an Array, and i have also displayed it onto the Screen, but now i want to restrict the user to Click only one button at a time, so is there anyway to do so ??

Note: I know i can use RadioButtons, but i need to have Buttons array because my application is somewhat like Calendar View (Consider Calendar View, where we can display "Day" value with the use of Button and then putting day value as 1, 2, 3 ,4,......31), now as user can select only date at a time, same way , i wants to have only one button click at a time.

Please Understand my requirement.

Comment: Your question isn't all clear. You do not *sellect* a button, you *click* it, and then something happens. And by definition (ignoring multi-touch), you can only click on one single button at a time. If what you want is to *select* a "button", what you really want is either a checkbox or radio buttons (as suggested by several answers below). If this isn't what you want, please clarify your question a bit better.

Comment: @Nailuj i have modified the question with "Click" , ok

Comment: Everybody is throwing about RadioButtons and i have also mentioned about that I must have Array of Buttons, but nobody is getting exactly. my bad luck

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani you keep trying to insist that you need to use Buttons instead of trying to describe why you have such a requirement. And again, as long as RadioButton is descendant of Button there is no much difference between them.

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani: as I said in the 1st comment: you cannot "select" a button! You *click* on a button, and then something happens. It is not possible to click on two buttons on the same time, so I do not understand your problem. As pointed out by Konstantin Burov, try to describe why there is such a requirement, then people might be able to help you.

Comment: Right, you can't do it with the Button class, but you can with ToggleButton. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep responding that Radio Buttons aren't an option but the reality is, what you are asking is exactly what a RadioGroup of Radio Buttons is designed to do.

You could do it with an Array of Buttons and I could explain how you'd do it but effectively I'd be explaining to you how to write a RadioGroup class which is pointless.

If 'the requirement' (which you haven't explained) doesn't want the default little circles used for RadioButtons then derive your own RadioButton subclass with a custom graphic which looks exactly like a normal Button then create a RadioGroup to handle everything else.

Comment: Maybe he want's an array of buttons which can be toggled,  but only one enabled/toggled at a time

Comment: Urrrm, yes...that's what RadioButtons do. The reason they're called 'radio' buttons is that in the old days when you pushed down a button on a radio, the other one that was down would pop-up and it wasn't possible to have more than one down at a time.

Comment: @Tseng Thank you Tseng, you got it exactly, thanx a lot

Comment: The important difference between RadioButtons and Buttons is that the former have the attribute 'checked' and corresponding methods isChecked() and setChecked(), the latter don't. It's the lack of this attribute that will make doing it with Buttons difficult. MisterSquonk's suggestion to override the style seems the obvious way of doing it

Comment: So does then ToggleButton Class. Documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Well Radio button isn't actually same as a button. A radio button usually is a selection with a label usually, a button has the label within the graphics. And on the other side, with toggle buttons you can also have multiple "buttons" enabled/toggled at the same time

Comment: @Tseng you're talking about old style radio buttons. As @MisterSquonk mentioned already, there is nothing complex to make RadioButton to look like regular button and still have RadioGroup advantages.

Comment: Well, actually there is other difference (other than having a label field which is located next to the radio button and not inside): With Toggle Button you can also have 0 (zero) toggles enabled, while in Radio one has to be chosen. I actually don't like the idea of abusing Objects and Classes for task they wasn't designed for

Comment: @Tseng not true, you always can have radio group where nothing is selected (and it is by default). Also I believe that RadioButton and RadioGroup fit the task much better then custom implementation based on ToggleButtons.

Comment: @Tseng: You're saying things that simply aren't true. And in fact they're 100% wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use radio buttons, what you're describing is the purpose of RadioButton to exist.

Comment: @Konstantin no choice for Radio buttons, As per the requirement, i must have Buttons Array

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani  RadioButton is descendant of Button, I do no see any problems of using it instead of regular button.

Comment: +1 to counterbalance stupid downvote. You didn't specify anywhere it had to be buttons. Why can you online use buttons?

Comment: also +1 to counterbalance this downvote

Comment: And who flagged this and Roflcoptr's answer as offensive? There's nothing even remotely offensive about these answers.

Comment: @FAlmarri @Konstantin Everybody is throwing about RadioButtons and i have also mentioned about that I must have Array of Buttons, but nobody is getting exactly.

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani you keep trying to insist that you need to use Buttons instead of trying to describe why you have such a requirement. And again, as long as RadioButton is descendant of Button there is no much difference between them.

Comment: Just to add to Konstantin Burov's answer: This is the Android documentation for `Button` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html And this is the Android documentation for `RadioButton` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html. As can be seen there, `RadioButton` is a subclass of `Button`, meaning that everything a `Button` can do, a `RadioButton` can also. A `RadioButton` *is* a `Button`, just with some extra features.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a RadioGroup (a lot of RadioButtons) instead.

Here is a good example:
http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/radiogroup/

Here is another tutorial:

[Anddev](http://www.anddev.org/basics_for_using_radio_buttons__buttons__message_box-t857.html)

Comment: i know i can do with RadioGroup, but i must have Buttons Array according to Requirement, so please

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. However, if you absolutely want to use a Array of Buttons, then I would use a flag for every button to check if it is clicked, and then if you click a button, set all other flags to false and the flag of the button you clicked to true. So you always now which one is selected

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in some of my comments, you can use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) instead of Button class.

I.e.

```
List<ToggleButton> buttonList = new List<ToggleButton>();
// Add your buttons here
buttonList.add(btn1);
buttonList.add(btn2); // etc

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        foreach(ToggleButton button : buttonList) {
            if(button==buttonView) {
                // That's the button which got clicked, enable the toggle
                button.setChecked(isChecked);
            } else {
                // That's all the other not-clicked on buttons, disable their toggle
                button.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach(ToggleButton button : buttonList) {
    // Now set the Listener from above to each of the buttons
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
}
```

This should do the trick, can't check on compiler/syntax errors here, as I'm at work :P

**Edit:**
Just forgot to add the code for setting the newly created Listener to all of the buttons

Comment: Thanx a lot , really a great job done by you even you are at work, i am going to try it and let you know soon!!

Comment: Why is ToggleButton ok with your requirement to only use button although RadioButton is not ok??

Comment: Obviously, since he asked for a solution with Buttons and not Radio buttons. But instead of answering and presenting him the next closest logical solution, you insist at your work around of abusing a radio button to do the same task. You can also create a ListView manually from just TextViews, but that's not practical neither, since there is already a done class for it. Same goes for Radio vs Toggle. Maybe you guys should first throw a look into the Android documentation, before insisting on some workarounds

Comment: Actually he could also use the `CompoundButton`, which is a button with states, but not additional stuff added in Radio, Toggle or CheckBox buttons, which is a thing all the have in common and is still a button by default w/o changing it's look or having some non-button functionality in it

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with android, I'm afraid, but the keyword here is "radio" - you should attempt to give this group of buttons the `radio` attribute.